# Updating Text View with a list of values in android app widget

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview, android-appwidget

I have an app widget that does some stuff in AsyncTask's doInBackground() method and the final steps are to get the list of store names, that looks like this:

```
Store storeObject=store.getStores().getItems().get(0).getStore();
String name= storeObject.getName();
//name of the store         
return name;
```

Right now I am getting the name at 0th position.
Now I want all the names of the stores (that are 27 in my code being fetched) in my widget text view one by one when you click a next button.

So how should I pass this name in my remote views back in onPostExecute() of AsyncTask.

```
updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view, name);
updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next, pendingIntent);
```

Where should I use a for loop? in doInBackground or onPostExcecute or both? How can I use loop in remoteviews and update it? Please please help. I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Its a list so I generated an index that's randomly updated, no need of loop.